# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined. Onclick/ onChange

Tags: javascript

TL;DR
getTotal should give me a total of these 2 functions summed together but it's throwing me an error instead:

Uncaught ReferenceError: getTotal is not defined
onchange http://127.0.0.1:3211/XyZPage/Untitled-1.html:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: getTotal is not defined
onclick http://127.0.0.1:3211/XyZPage/Untitled-1.html:1
code:

```
var service_prices= new Array();
service_prices=["0"]= 0;
service_prices=["1500"]= 1500;
service_prices=["4000"]= 4000;
service_prices=["8000"]= 8000;
function getServicePrice(){
    var serviceOptionPrice=0;
    var form = document.forms["formulario"];
    var selectedOption = form.elements["servicePrice"];
    serviceOptionPrice = service_prices[selectedOption.value];
    return serviceOptionPrice;
}
//checkbox calculation//

function extraPrices(){
    var extraPrices=0;
    var form=document.forms["formulario"];
    var selectedBox = form.elements["selectedBox"];
    if(selectedBox.checked==true){
        extraPrices=400;
    }
    return extraPrices;
}

//total final calc//

function getTotal(){
    var finalPrice = getServicePrice() + extraPrices();
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= "eddies" + finalPrice;
}
```

I've tried couple fixes from threads here but nothing worked so far. JS alongside html https://jsfiddle.net/j1t68npf/

Comment: where are you calling `getTotal()`?

Comment: So either you have an error in the script keeping the code from rendering or you used a module. Hard to guess with what is provided.

Comment: @GrafiCode on <Select onchange="getTotal()"> & in each checkbox input onclick="getTotal()". I've updated my post with jsfiddle to reproduce this

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @blaze2004, um... that's not true. In HTML attributes are case insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a several syntax errors in your JS which prevent the parser from reaching the `getTotal()` definition. So it remains undefined.

The offending sections is:

```
service_prices=["0"]= 0;
service_prices=["1500"]= 1500;
service_prices=["4000"]= 4000;
service_prices=["8000"]= 8000;
```

If you repair this you will no longer get the undefined error.

After this is fixed there are several other coding errors which, when resolved will get you this:

```js
//reference the form by it's ID//

//Dropdown list calculation//
var service_prices = new Array();
service_prices["0"] = 0;
service_prices["1500"] = 1500;
service_prices["4000"] = 4000;
service_prices["8000"] = 8000;

function getServicePrice() {
  var serviceOptionPrice = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedOption = form.querySelector("#servicePrice");
  if (service_prices[selectedOption.value]) {
    serviceOptionPrice = service_prices[selectedOption.value];
  }
  return serviceOptionPrice;
}
//checkbox calculation//

function extraPrices() {
  var extraPrices = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedBoxes = form.querySelectorAll("#selectedBox");
  selectedBoxes.forEach(box => {
    if (box.checked == true) {
      extraPrices += 400;
    }
  })

  return extraPrices;
}

//total final calc//

function getTotal() {
  var finalPrice = getServicePrice() + extraPrices();
  document.getElementById("result").value = "eddies" + finalPrice;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">




  <p> Type of Service</p>
  <select name="serviço" id="servicePrice" onchange="getTotal()">
    <option value="none">Select a service</option>
    <option value="1500">1500€</option>
    <option value="4000">4000€</option>
    <option value="8000">8000€</option>
  </select>

  <!--checkbox-->
  <h1>DESIRED EXTRAS</h1>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="4" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Who we are
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="5" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Where we are
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="6" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Gun Gallery
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="7" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> eCommerce
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="8" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Internal Mangement
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="9" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> News
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox"> Social Network
  <br> <br> <br>
  <!--result-->
  <h1>Estimated Total</h1>

  <input type="text" class="InStyle" disabled id="result">

</form>
```

It bears mentioning that you should not re-use ID values in html, they are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Thanks mate, running the snippet and it's working flawlessly, albeit I'm now confused as of why it does not run in my vsc. Going through my code again trying to see what's causing what, the bits above at the very least I know they are working when isolated

Comment: update: found the culprit and it was a "." missing from script

Answer (score 0):

This is a corrected version of your code, as stated in comments there were multiple syntax errors, but most importantly, you're handling the checkbox collection as if it were a single checkbox.
In this version I iterate all checkboxes and accumulate `400` for each checked one.

```js
//reference the form by it's ID//

//Dropdown list calculation//
var service_prices = new Array();
service_prices["0"] = 0;
service_prices["1500"] = 1500;
service_prices["4000"] = 4000;
service_prices["8000"] = 8000;

function getServicePrice() {
  var serviceOptionPrice = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedOption = form.elements["servicePrice"];

  if (selectedOption.value != "none") {
    serviceOptionPrice = service_prices[selectedOption.value];
  }
  return serviceOptionPrice;
}
//checkbox calculation//

function extraPrices() {
  var extraPrices = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedBox = form.elements["selectedBox"];
  selectedBox.forEach(el => {
    if (el.checked) {
      extraPrices += 400;
    }
  })
  return extraPrices;
}

//total final calc//

function getTotal() {
  var finalPrice = getServicePrice() + extraPrices();
  document.getElementById("result").value = "eddies" + finalPrice;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario" name="formulario">

  <p> Type of Service</p>
  <select name="serviço" id="servicePrice" onchange="getTotal()">
    <option value="none">Select a service</option>
    <option value="1500">1500€</option>
    <option value="4000">4000€</option>
    <option value="8000">8000€</option>
  </select>

  <!--checkbox-->
  <h1>DESIRED EXTRAS</h1>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="4" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Who we are
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="5" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Where we are
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="6" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Gun Gallery
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="7" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> eCommerce
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="8" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> Internal Mangement
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="9" id="selectedBox" onclick="getTotal()"> News
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox"> Social Network
  <br> <br> <br>
  <!--result-->
  <h1>Estimated Total</h1>

  <input type="text" class="InStyle" disabled id="result">


</form>
```

Comment: Thank you aswell, this bit runs perfectly, always good to know another way to things, as I've mentioned in other comment I still get the same error so my problem may also lay elsewhere, going through my code again and see what ticks because at the very least the bits above when isolated work 100%

Comment: update: found the culprit and it was a "." missing from script